# Keep original size when export image from illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I use Illustrator to export `.png` files for my app, but when I select medium(`150dpi`) and high(`300dpi`) resolution in the PNG options box, it exports in a bigger dimension than my artboard( my artboard  is `48px x 48px` and the results are `56px x 53px` and `112px x 87px`). How can I save my images with artboard size?

Answer (score 36):

Export your artwork in following way:
1. Tick "Use Artboards" and then save
2. In png option, use screen (72ppi)
3. Now hit "OK".

Now you will get actual size of your artwork.

Comment: Check "Use Artboards" in Export dialog box.

Comment: Not work for me! :( My artboard's size (29, 29) then exported I got png file with size (30, 30) !

Comment: Which version of Ai are you using?

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you save like this at 72 ppi, you can then save only the artboard at a higher resolution the second time around. Works.